# Angular 14, ng serve error - @ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js - Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

I'm working with angular 14 and node 16  and typescript. I was working normally, but now when i execute the ng serve command, i get the following error:

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

here is my ng version

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have some files that have circular dependencies (import/export)

Comment: Yes, i check it out  and yes it was

Comment: I had this problem when a module was accidentally importing itself.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

check the modules import , you may have circular importation

Comment: Seems like it only bothers me, that in Angular the error description is not related to the real reason.

Comment: Got AppModule imported in one of the child modules after generating component in Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 15):

I got this error, as I stupidly included a package in both `declarations` *and* `imports` in my *app.module.ts* file:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CanvasJSChart,
    . . .
  ],
  imports: [
    CanvasJSChart,
    . . .
```

Moral of the story: don't drink and code.

Comment: Had a similar issue, I was mistakenly importing the same module itself, instead of another module with a similar name

Answer (score 7):

Please check module routing carefully. You may have declared same component both in declarations and imports.

play it in this way....

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FooterComponent,
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports:[
    FooterComponent,
    NavbarComponent
  ]
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: it will be helpful if you explain what the first command do